# i'm trying to use store procedure with pdo in php but getting fatal error

Tags: php, pdo

i want to make  a store procedure in php mysql
which is

```
SELECT * FROM countries WHERE name LIKE ?"
```

and call it in a function using pdo like function.php

```
<?php
Class Get{


    public function GetWord($word){
        include("conn.php");
        $result=$conn->query("CALL GetWord($word)");
        return $this->result;
    }
}
?>
```

and call this function in main file can anyone tell me how to do it
my approach is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search').keyup(function(){
            var search=$('#search').val();
            if($.trim(search.length)==0){
                $('#result').html('Try to find more words')
            }
            else{
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'search.php',
                    data:{'search':search},
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#result').html(data);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
```

getting error like

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Get::prepare() in C:\PHPP\htdocs\learnbootstrap\search.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\PHPP\htdocs\learnbootstrap\search.php on line 7-->
```

this is my search.php

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $search=$_POST['search'];
    $query=$conn->prepare(GetWords($word));
    $query->execute(["%$search%"]);
    $count=$query->rowCount();
    if($count == 0){
            echo "sorry no results were found";
    }
    else{
        echo "<table class='table table-hover'>";
        }
```

this is my store procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetWords`(IN pword varchar(200))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM dictionarysearch where word like pword;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Get {

        public function getWord($word){
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL GetWord(?);");
            $stmt->execute([ $word ]);
            $stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['search'])){

        $search=$_POST['search'];
        $G = new Get();
        $result = $G->getWord($search);

        var_dump($result);

    }
```

In $result you can get array of result from your query

Comment: so what about store procedure because i couldnt make a store procedure using wildcard which can be used to select and i thanks for your precious time

Comment: Hi john it is still showing error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\PHPP\htdocs\learnbootstrap\function2.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\PHPP\htdocs\learnbootstrap\function2.php(21): Get->getWord('articulate') #1 {main}